# SQLPLUS: Set multiple values if variable != blah

Tags: oracle, sql-update, sqlplus, case-statement

So, for the first time in my life I wasn't able to find my answer here and had to create my own question.

Here is my script:

```
 UPDATE EC_PLAN_OFFERED
    SET AUTHOR_ID = 'ATTESTATION_FIX', 
        -- MIN_ESSENTIAL_COV_IN = '&&7',
        -- MIN_VALUE_PLAN_IN = '&&8',
        DEPENDENT_COV_AVAL_IN = '&&3', 
        SPOUSE_COVERAGE_AVL_IN = '&&4', 
        SELF_INSURED_IN = '&&5'
    WHERE EMPLOYEE_ONLY_CVG_LVL_IN = 'Y'
        -- AND MEDICAL_PLAN_ID = '&&6'  
        AND (WAIVED_COVERAGE_IN = 'N' OR WAIVED_COVERAGE_IN IS NULL) 
        AND AUTHOR_ID <> 'IMPORT_NON_EMPLOYEE'
        AND OFFER_ID IN (
            SELECT OFFER_ID 
            FROM EC_COVERAGE_OFFER 
            WHERE NVL(COVERAGE_START_DT, EVENT_DT) < TO_DATE('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY')
        );
```

You can see that I have some of the SET commented out.  How could I do this on the fly?

For example, the feed I get has a '-' in the field they don't want updated.  A 'Y' or 'N' is passed otherwise and is what is placed in the field.

I tried several variations of:

```
CASE WHEN &&7 != '-'  THEN ', MIN_ESSENTIAL_COV_IN = &&7' END
```

hoping it would place the line when I needed it, but that doesn't work as intended.

Please note this is SQLPLUS and being called via '.bat'.

Any suggestions other than use another language lol?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your need, you can try something like this:

```
MIN_ESSENTIAL_COV_IN = decode('&&7','-',MIN_ESSENTIAL_COV_IN, '&&7' )
```

This says to always update the value of the column in this way:

```
if &&7 = '-'
    update MIN_ESSENTIAL_COV_IN with its value ( so, do not update)
else 
    update MIN_ESSENTIAL_COV_IN to &&7
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I implemented this but now get:
"ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: It actually works!  This is a great function that i've never seen anywhere lol.  I had to add a ',' at the end of the call.  Thank you!

Comment: Great!  Done!  I am toying with this too: AND MEDICAL_PLAN_ID like decode('&&6', '*', '%', '&&6') - Should work...